# Debug remote server [PHP app] on my local machine [PhpStorm+Xdebug]

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to debug remote server (AWS EC2 Ubuntu), where there is a PHP application. I use PhpStorm locally on my Windows machine. I can not debug the app on the server.

I have Googled a lot and found a lot of explanations, but stuck. I have installed Xdebug on the server and locally. I have setup the SFTP connection in PhpStorm, so it has the Server and can synchronize. The `PhpStorm->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug - [Validate]` says everything is OK, when I choose Remote Web Server

When I click Start listening for PHP Debug connections in the PhpStorm IDE, I can debug the PHP code with breakpoints. The files are exactly the same as on my server. But nothing happens right now.

Comment: How exactly your remote server is connected to the IDE workstation? Is it possible to connect over TCP 9000 port (default) from your server to the IDE?

Comment: your best option is to use a tunnel over ssh that does a port forwarding from the server to your computer, there are many tunneling softwares out there available depending on which OS you are using

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost; xdebug should be able to call back home; ie the local computer running phpStorm.

Here is a quick checklist

can the remote connect to local directly? Can the remote host connect to local hosts xdebug port (generally 9000)?

IF yes;

> is xdebug configuration correct? Here is an example for a direct connection between remote and local:
>
> > xdebug.remote_enable = 1
> >
> > xdebug.remote_port = 900
> >
> > xdebug.remote_connect_back = On

IF No;

> there should be a way for remote to connect back to local. One option would be using an ssh tunnel. For that; xdebug configuration on remote should be amended accordingly; like:
>
> > xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
> >
> > xdebug.remote_port = 9001
> >
> > xdebug now tries to connect its own port; 9001 which is actually a tunnel to your localhost; port 9000
> >
> > you can create a tunnel with ssh on *nix; Putty on win*

Also, xdebug log files are indispensible whide debugging problems; be sure that xdebug IS creating logs; check them; example:

> xdebug.remote_log = /var/tmp/xdebug.log

After all those are set; activate PHPStorm's listening mode and start debugging.

Also; may be good to remember the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html)